# Search template page in Drupal 7

Tags: 7, theming, search

In search results page,

the search form and search results are in the content area.

Can we insert another block between the search form and results list? Or adjust the order for example put "spelling-suggestions" on the top of the form, then add another block between the form and search extra provided by display suite.

If without existing templates, guessing we will have to modify the $node['content'].

Any ideas are welcome, thanks

```
<form id="search-form" class="search-form" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post" action="/search/all/test">
<div class="spelling-suggestions">
<div class="ds-search-extra">One result</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

My current method is dirty:

```
  $build['search_form_resort'] = $build['search_form'];
  unset($build['search_form']);
```

Then put the $build['search_form_resort'] under the $build['suggestions'].

Read more:
[http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21search%21search.pages.inc/function/search_view/7](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!search!search.pages.inc/function/search_view/7)